# CocoaPods added a new project but I can't add it to existing GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository, xcode5, push

I am fairly new to GitHub and I can't figure out how to add a folder to my current repository.  I was able to create a repository and push my first project up to it.

I created a new branch, checked it out, and then added pods to it using CocoaPods.  I have everything working the way I like and would like to push everything back up to GitHub.  Xcode does not recognize the new Pods folder as part of the branch, nor can I add the files to it.

I have the GitHub application on my MacBook and it recognized the new workspace that was created by CocoaPods and pushed it up to the GitHub repository.  But it doesn't recognize the Pods folder either.  I tried dragging the folder onto the GitHub app but it want's to create a new repository.

All I need to do is include the Pods directory in my existing GitHub branch.  How is this accomplished?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the problem.  For some reason the .gitignore file had the PODS folder included. Then I used the "git add" command to add the folder.  Xcode still appeared to have problems committing the new files, so I used the GitHub application to perform the commit.  Once that was finished I went back to Xcode and pushed the latest changes up to GitHub.  It finally worked.